# Pylint: self.xxx is not callable

Tags: python, oop, pylint

I am unsure why I am given this error when I coded my class as follows:

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    self.architecture = {"backbone": None, "bottleneck": None, "head": None}
    self.architecture_name['backbone'] = model
    
    ...
    
    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.architecture['backbone'](x)
        ...
```

The error from pylint is when I call `self.architecture['backbone'](x)`, the code still runs, but I just wonder if there is anything wrong with this.

Comment: pylint doesn't know that you're assigning functions to the dictionary entries.

Comment: Maybe if you add type hints it won't complain.

Comment: This code runs? How is `self` defined in the class scope? And `self.architecture_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the function in the dictionary literal instead of assigning it later.

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    self.architecture = {"backbone": model, "bottleneck": None, "head": None}
```